# Minicom enable echo by default and set color for local echo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-port, minicom

To enable the echo with Minicom I use the combination Ctrl+A E, I was wondering if there is a way to activate the echo automatically without having to use this key combination every time?

Also is there a way to change the color of echo text?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To enable local echo permanently in minicom, you can:

1. Ensure you are in your home directory and run `minicom`
2. Turn on local echo with `Ctrl-Z` and then `E`.
3. Saving the minicom settings with `Ctrl-Z` and then `O`. Select `Save setup as dfl." or 'Save setup as`.
4. If you select 'Save setup as`, use the name` .minirc.dfl`.This file will be saved in your home directory and used by minicom when running under your user.

I sometimes find that this does not work when saving to the global defaults file. You may have to manually add/edit this file. See [this page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/minicom#:%7E:text=like%20a%20charm!-,Files,-Minicom%20keeps%20it%27s) for the location of the global minicom config file on your system.

You can add/edit the `.minirc.dfl` file in your home directory if you just want to make changes for your user.

In either case, add the line `pu localecho        Yes` to the defaults file.

[This is a very useful thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/minicom-default-duplex-minirc-dfl-setting-554543/) of available minicom settings.